# Android JNI: Cannot call functions in non-Activity class

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am using jni and I can call java functions in regular activity from c++ class but when I try to call java functions in non activity class, my code does not work.

I mean

```
 jclass activityclass = env->FindClass("com/example/test/MyActivity);
 jmethodID methodID = env->GetMethodID(activityclass,"FunctionName","()V");
 env ->CallVoidMethod(obj,methodID);
```

This works.
When I try to call same function(with same name) from non activity regular java class, it doesnt work.

```
 jclass regularclass = env->FindClass("com/example/test/MyRegularClass);
 jmethodID methodID = env->GetMethodID(regularclass ,"FunctionName","()V");
 env ->CallVoidMethod(obj,methodID);
```

Why I cannot call function in non activity class? What is my mistake?

My MyRegularClass

```
public class MyRegularClass{

  public static void FunctionName(){
 Log.i("Java Worked","Java Worked");
 }
}
```

My Activity classs

```
 public class MyActivity{

 system.load.library("mylib");

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 ....
 ....
 testJNI();
 }

  public static void FunctionName(){
 Log.i("Activity Worked","Activity  Worked");
 }

 public native void testJNI();
 }
```

Comment: No enough info here. Anything that is activity related requires a valid `Context`, and your 'regular' class probably doesn't have one. Do show more code and explain what your 'FunctionName', etc. do.

Comment: FunctionName is a just a name. My regular class doesnt have a context. It has a some methods and it just a regular java class. Why I cannot call this methods? I can post whole class codes but they are just regular class and activity

Comment: First, define 'does not work'. Include stacktraces and real code (excerpts).

Comment: Any chance you are proguard obfuscating the non-activity class, but automatically preserving the activity class since activities are known to need to be externally reachable by un-obfuscated name?  Or that the non-activity class is getting eliminated from the build since it's never apparently used from java?  If you know how to decompile an apk that could be a quick check.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov I edited my question. This a small test application. In my big application, I need to call many functions from non-activity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `GetStaticMethodID()` and `CallStaticVoidMethod()` for static methods. This has nothing to do with  the methods being in activities or not.

Comment: No It did not work. Also I remped static keyword from method, results is same. I can call from activity but not from class.

Comment: I edited my question. This a small test application. In my big application, I need to call many functions from non-activity class. Also I do not use android debugger but I can put log in cpp code. Code cannot arrive after call void method.

Comment: Did you check `methodID` for `null`? And the debugger is generally a good idea :)

Comment: I was not able to set up debugger for ndk. It was not easy.

Comment: I am not c++ person, but I checked (if(&methodid ==0) and methodis is not 0

Comment: You probably want `methodid ==0`. http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html You most likely have a bug in your code, but debugging via SO might not be too efficient :)

Comment: You are correct. It is my mistake. when I change clas like jclass cls = env -> GetObjectClass(obj), it worked. For activity class, we do not need "GetObjectClass"

Comment: Yay :) Glad it works for you. This is not directly related to activities, but to getting the class of an instance as opposed to the static one. Cf. this: `Thing obj =new Thing(); Class clazz = obj.getClass()` to this: `Class clazz = Thing.class`.